# How to set different default programs in windows explorer and command line

Tags: windows

I have some ruby scripts and i want to have 2 different default programs for a same file, one program if i double click it in windows explorer just to edit the code (for example in Sublime Text), but when i run it from command line i want the script to be executed. I am using windows 10.

So far, i have set default program for windows explorer sublime text, so the script opens just fine.

In command line i have set

```
E:\projects\Ruby>assoc .rb
.rb=Ruby.File
```

and

```
E:\projects\Ruby>ftype Ruby.File
Ruby.File=C:\bin\ruby200\bin\ruby.exe "%1" %*
```

Also i have set `.RB` en the `PATHEXT` Environment Variables so i just type the name of the script. But the problem is, when i do that, it launches Sublime Text instead of running the script.

If i change default program from windows explorer, it runs just of from command line, but of course it doesn't open sublime text if i double click it.

Is it possible to have 2 different default programs then? One form command line, and another form windows explorer when i double click some script?

Comment: Why not just use the context menu `Open With Sublime Text` for the explorer option, and leave the file association with `ruby.exe`. That's how I work in Python...

Comment: And that's how i do it now. But in my pc for some reason does not remember the path of the ruby executable in the options of "Open with", so every time i have to right click>"chose another app">"more apps">go to the end of the list and select "look for another apps">then browse for ruby executable. Seems a lot of steps when i could just double click it.
From command line it's easier though, if i have a script named `test.rb`, instead of just write `test`, i can write `ruby test.rb`. Still, seems innecesary when i had set up file associations to open with ruby interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not easy to do with GUI but it can be done through command line. First of all you have to make your association *dynamic*. To do it you have to use `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value type for registry key containing `.rb` file association. `REG_EXPAND_SZ` won't be used literally but expanded (=environment variables replaced with their actual values). You can create association with assoc but then you have to use `reg add` to change it because default type is `REG_SZ`. Program path must be something like this:

```
%RUBY_PROGRAM% "%1" %*
```

Where `%RUBY_PROGRAM%` is the name of - so far - not existing environment variable. Now you can give a default value to that variable:

```
setx RUBY_PROGRAM c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

Now close your command prompt and go to change its properties (from GUI). As alternative you may create a new shortcut for your *modified* command prompt. Command to execute has to be this:

```
%comspec% /k ""c:\setup_ruby.bat""
```

`/k` lets you execute given batch file at startup, in that batch you just need to set a different value for `%RUBY_PROGRAM%` environment variable:

```
SET RUBY_PROGRAM=C:\bin\ruby200\bin\ruby.exe
```

Now each time you run that special shortcut you will directly execute your Ruby programs. If you don't want to create a special shortcut and you want to apply this *rule* to every command prompt (regardless where it has been open) then you can add an entry to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` registry key.

Note that you may just put `ftype` in startup script (also providing a *quit* batch) but that will affect all applications until you close command line prompt (even if you double click file from Windows Explorer).